# How do I fill a certain area with a specific block?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image]

I’m on Minecraft version :1.2.13 and I am building a castle. I don’t want to go through the pain of clicking for a giant floor. So how do I fill a space?